# cause the main process wait until another process is finished

Tags: java, process

I have a synchronization problem in java.
I want my main thread to wait until process "p1" is finished. 
I have used "waitfor" method. it has not worked for me.

```
Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start /MIN " + path + "aBatchFile.bat" );
p1.waitFor();
```

Could anybody help me please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It should work.  What's the return value of p1.waitFor()?

Comment: In what way does this not work?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the `Process` object you get back from `exec()` represents the instance of `cmd.exe` that you start. Your instance of `cmd.exe` does one thing: it starts a batch file and *then exits* (without waiting for the batch file, because that's what the `start` command does). At that point, your `waitFor()` returns.

To avoid this problem, you should be able to run the batch file directly:

```
Process p1 = runtime.exec(path + "aBatchFile.bat");
p1.waitFor();
```

Alternately, try the `/wait` command line option:

```
Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start /wait /MIN " + path + "aBatchFile.bat" ); 
p1.waitFor();
```

Comment: yes - also I think removing start should make you wait as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

putting /wait does not work for me again. It does not wait the main thread.
if I remove "start" or if I remove "cmd /c start /wait /MIN ", the process p1 is not run at all.
I checked them. 
Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: @Shadi: And what happens if you remove "start /MIN" so your command is `exec("cmd /c " + path + "aBatchFile.bat")`?

Comment: @Shadi: I suggest you avoid the use of batch files.

Comment: However, If I do not use batch file, and for example, I want to call an "exe" file, I need to pause my main thread until the execution of the "exe" file is finished. So, how can I do that?

Comment: @Shadi: Exactly as you originally wrote in your question (except don't use `cmd`). Just run your executable directly.